# sort 2D array based on two columns

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have 2D array and it has 2 columns and I want to sort this.

---

input is this:

first column..... second column

3......................2

4......................9

3......................1

5......................0

1......................2

---

output is this:

first column..... second column

5......................0

4......................9

3......................2

3......................1

1......................2

---

I beginner in Java.

please help me whit a code of function(mySort(int[][] arr) to sort the array.

Comment: I do order by second first, and then order by first.

Comment: If you haven't done it yet, then *please* take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort with your custom comparator:

```
Arrays.sort(datas, new Comparator<Integer[]>() {
         @Override
         public int compare(Integer[] entry1, Integer[] entry2) {
                if(entry1[0] == entry2[0]){
                       return entry2[1] - entry1[1];
                }
                return entry2[0] - entry1[0];
         }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When using java 8, you can also do it like this:

```
    Comparator<Integer[]> comparator = Comparator.comparing(x -> x[0])
    .thenComparing(x -> x[1]);
    // when
    Arrays.sort(a, comparator.reversed());
```

Comment: You will want to add `.thenComparing(x -> x[1])`.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the second column:)

Answer (score 1):

For a n*2 array

Sorting based on column1 (ascending)

```
    Arrays.sort(arr, (a,b)-> {
            if(a[0] == b[0]){
                return a[1] - b[1];
         }
         return a[0] - b[0];
  });
```

//here 'arr' is an n*2 array

Sorting based on column1 (descending)

```
Arrays.sort(arr, (a,b)-> {
            if(b[0] == a[0]){
                return b[1] - a[1];
         }
         return b[0] - a[0];
  });
```

Sorting based on column2 (ascending)

```
 Arrays.sort(arr, (a,b)-> {
            if(a[1] == b[1]){
                return a[0] - b[0];
         }
         return a[1] - b[1];
  });
```

Sorting based on column2 (descending)

```
Arrays.sort(arr, (a,b)-> {
            if(b[1] == a[1]){
                return b[0] - a[0];
         }
         return b[1] - a[1];
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In java 8, you can use

```java
Arrays.sort(array, (a,b) -> (b[0],a[0])); // in a descending order
```